# Cannot get access to a struct that was defined in a base class

Tags: c++, c++-templates

I implemented BinaryTree class and inside the definition of BinaryTree I defined the structure "BinaryNode".

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H
#include <iostream>
#define SPACE 10

template <class T,class U>
class BinaryTree
{
protected:

    typedef struct BinaryNode{
        U data;
        T key;
        struct BinaryNode* left;
        struct BinaryNode* right;
        struct BinaryNode* parent;
        BinaryNode(const T _key, const U& _data): key(_key), data(_data){}
        virtual ~BinaryNode(){
        if(left)
            delete left;
        if(right)
            delete right;
        }

    }BinaryNode;
    BinaryNode* root;
```

Now, I want to implement another sort of BinaryTree, which is a Heap. So I want to inherit from BinaryTree and add one field, this field is a pointer of type BinaryNode, which points the last leaf in the heap (heaps are complete trees, so that if the last level is not full, the last leaf is the leaf in the right tip).

```
#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H
#include "BinaryTree.h"


template <class T,class U>
class Heap : public BinaryTree<T,U>
{
public:
//|--------------------- Constructors ----------------------|
    Heap() : lastLeaf(NULL) {}

//|-------------------- Private fields ---------------------|
private:
    BinaryNode* lastLeaf;
```

When I try to compile I get this error:

```
error: 'BinaryNode' does not name a type; did you mean 'BinaryTree'?|
```

Now if I try instead:

```
struct BinaryNode* lastLeaf;
```

In addition, everywhere I use `BinaryNode*` in the program, I get the error:

```
error: 'BinaryNode' has not been declared
```

So its not just in the field definition.

What can I do?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Side note: C++ learned a lot from C. One thing is learned was the `typedef struct` trick, and C++ baked it in. `typedef struct BinaryNode{ ... }BinaryNode;` and `struct BinaryNode{ ... };` have the same result.

Comment: @user4581301 actually without typedef it requires me to write struct everywhere

Comment: There's something else wrong. No clue what. If you have a solution for it, that takes a bit of pressure off, but you still need a bit of paranoia. You might have merely hidden the obvious effect of a problem that will bite harder somewhere else now that it's gone undercover.

Comment: @user4581301 What do you mean? right now everthing works fine, I have run some tests

Comment: What I mean is the only time in C++ that you should have to use the class or struct keywords is when you're declaring or defining a type, in a template declaration, or when you have a naming collision and need to disambiguate. If you can't `BinaryNode* lastLeaf;` The first two don't apply and that means you likely have a naming collision somewhere. That said, if you have a naming collision, the `typedef` should *also* collide, so WTF...? There's something odd in the code.

Comment: @user4581301 Maybe its a fitcher of a latest vresion of c++ and I'm using an older one

Comment: Unlikely. What I'm talking about dates back to the earliest formal C++ Standards.

Answer (score 3):

You derived class doesn't know what template parameters to apply to `BinaryNode`.  Therefore, you need:

```
template <class T,class U>
class Heap : public BinaryTree<T,U>
{
    // ...
    typename BinaryTree<T,U>::BinaryNode* lastLeaf;
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/355V0nOZtkvAAQhD)

---

As per @AdrianMole's comment, clang needs the `typename` keyword here, so I have added that to my answer.  And you don't need to use `typedef`, please see updated demo.

Comment: Clang says: *warning : missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'BinaryTree<T, U>::BinaryNode' [-Wtypename-missing]*

Comment: @AdrianMole So it does.  gcc doesn't seem to care.  Answer amended, thank you.

Comment: It actually solved the problem of the definition of lastLeaf, but everywhere I use BinaryNode* in my problem I get the error: error: 'BinaryNode' has not been declared|. What else can I do?

Comment: New problem is usually best handled as a new question. The more you pack into a question the bulkier and less useful a question is.

Comment: @user4581301 It is the same problem - I could not get access to the structure I defened in a base class. Nevertheless - I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line:

```
typedef struct BinaryTree<T,U>::BinaryNode BinaryNode;
```

to the beggining of the file solved it.

Comment: In the modern world, that might be better expressed as a `using` statement (and maybe don't re-use the name `BinaryNode` here).

Comment: "Do this" is not very useful without a "Why you do this"

Comment: @user4581301 Agree. But I honsetly cannot provide a good explanation, I assume that my compiler requires to write struct BinaryTree<T,U>::BinaryNode each time Im using BinaryNode, so that the line I wrote replace the long expression with just BinaryNode.